# Git undo pushed merge and delete its history

Tags: git, git-merge

I made an accidental merge to master and pushed it, now master has all the commits from dev. I want to revert the commits from master and delete its history without changing dev. How can I do that?

Comment: git revert <commit>?

Comment: but that will show in history, I want to clean the history too

Comment: You need to `git reset --hard <sha-1>` followed by `git push --force` to overwrite the current state.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The last commit can be removed with: `git reset --hard HEAD^`.

Sometimes there might be situations, when you need to remove a commit from the "middle" of branch. Here comes to the rescue interactive rebase: `git rebase -i <commit>^`. You just need to drop an unwanted commit (it should appear at the top of the list).

If the changes you undone were available in remote, they also should be removed from there with force push: `git push --force`.

However, rewriting the history of a branch, that has been shared with someone, is not a good way of undoing changes. Instead, consider to use `git revert <commit>`. This is the more robust and correct way in this situation.

I'd recommend to read [Git Branching - Rebasing](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing). Chapter "The Perils of Rebase" is explaining why rewriting the public history is not a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ git revert -m 1 <merge-commit-hash>
```

1. git revert will make sure that a new commit is created to revert the effects of that unwanted merge. This is in contrast to git reset, where we effectively "remove" a commit from the history. That's also the reason why git revert is a better solution in cases where you've already pushed to a remote.
2. The `-m` 1 option tells Git that we want to keep the parent side of the merge (which is the branch we had merged into).
3. Finally, also make sure to provide the correct commit hash: for the git reset example above, we had to provide the commit before the merge; when using git revert, however, we have to specify the actual merge commit's hash.

https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/undo-git-merge/

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `reflog` to find out where was master pointing to before the merge, and use the `reset` command to reset it to that. The commits won't be deleted because there're still in dev, but master won't have them. If you really want to delete those, i.e., also reset dev, you may do, and the orphan commits will eventually be garbage-collected.

Here's an example, but don't just use it as a recipe, rather, read some more about Git and how Git works (git structures) and practice elsewhere (other branches / other repos), and when you're confident come back to this one and try.

[Recovering lost commits](http://effectif.com/git/recovering-lost-git-commits)

Comment: You seem to be saying there's a branch beyond master you've pushed master content to, which you cannot reset.

Comment: you are saying `git reset`, right? Won't it just reset the changes at my local changes?

Comment: @ShubhamChaudhary - Having pushed the branch means that if you reset, you then have to do a "forced" push, and this has costs. It doesn't mean reset won't work; it means that either fixing it is worth coordinating with the other developers to handle the forced push, or it isn't.  If it isn't, there's nothing you can do to clean up the history.