# How can I clean up my GitHub fork's commits and branch to make clean PRs in the future?

Tags: git, github, pull-request, git-fork

###### My issue in short:

I was contributing to [a repo on GitHub](https://github.com/brookjeynes/slime-rancher-2-interactive-map/), so I [forked](https://github.com/rodriguezrrp/slime-rancher-2-interactive-map), and I created a new branch, made my additions, and submitted a successful PR back to the origin repo (#18 in it). The result now is that I now fear I have muddied my fork's history such that I can't neatly contribute any more with it.

I am seeking a solution that will not muddy the origin repo's commit history for any future pull requests I make from this fork.

###### Steps and graphs of my process:

My feature branch was named `added-pods`. I was then going to submit a pull request of my changes to be accepted to the original repo on GitHub.

**What it looked like before pull request:**

```
main     --A
            \
added-pods   B--C--D--E
```

**What I *expected* pull request on origin to do to my fork:**

```
main     --A------------F-
            \          /
added-pods   B--C--D--E
```

Origin:

```
main     --A--B--C--D--E--F     (or  A-----F)
```

**What it *actually* looked like after pull request and syncing:**

My fork:

```
main     --A------------F
            \          
added-pods   B--C--D--E
```

Origin:

```
main     --A------------F
```

There was no difference in the code between my feature branch and main now. Yet, my feature branch wasn't visually merged, locally or on GitHub. It appears as if a 'magical' commit (F) showed up in my fork's main branch and that my feature branch was never merged. This was different than what I saw *other contributor's* PRs into the origin repo (from the origin repo's graph perspective). I couldn't see how what I did was different from theirs.
I tried fixing by PR-ing my fork's feature branch into my fork's main branch. **After a PR inside my fork**, [it looks like this](https://github.com/rodriguezrrp/slime-rancher-2-interactive-map/network):

```
main     --A------------F---G
            \              /
added-pods   B--C--D--E---/
```

Now I have a PR commit G. And in the commit history on GitHub, the difference between F and G is nothing, so it looks like a pointless and confusing commit. *I may have a fundamental misunderstanding about pull-requests*. I thought merges, *including PRs*, bring commits from a branch onto the targeted branch's commit history. The PR commit F *did not* seem to do that.

From searching SO questions, PRs can't be undone, only 'reverted', which I read would only add another commit in the GitHub history, G won't disappear. *I believe I want to remove G but get a connecting line*, because G literally adds confusion to me.

**Summary question:** Where do I reset to, or branch from, so I avoid muddying the history of the upstream or origin repository when pull-requesting in the future? In other words, keeping it clean and no 'useless' commits?

I have also considered [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102297/how-do-i-clean-up-my-github-fork-so-i-can-make-clean-pull-requests) but because PRs can't be undone I think those options won't work because of my PR inside my own fork. I can locally reset to F with `git reset HEAD^` suggested from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48289008) but that didn't fix my "unmerged branch" problem.

Comment: It looks like your PR was squash-merged into the upstream repo. At that point, you can delete your local branch, usually. To "clean up", you could delete your fork and clone again?

Comment: @BenjaminW. Thanks that explains the single commit. I hesitated to delete the branch without saving the individual commits first, hence I wanted to merge to main. I could do that nuking "clean up" but I would prefer not if possible. So I got the idea of making a new branch which I'd switch to the "default" in the repo, branching it off from the squash-merge commit. And I'd need to switch the upstream to go into that new one. It's worth a shot. I may resort to deleting the local branches eventually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by doing a bit of rewriting the history on the `main` branch using a new commit. Most of this was helped out by [this SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67695450/git-detached-head-make-current-head) about detached HEADs that I found. Note you should **not** rewrite history in public repos unless you know it won't affect anyone. Because my fork was small, it was only 1 commit, and I know of no other forks that came from mine, I was confident this is a safe move.

1. **I went back one commit** on the main branch. This made my local HEAD point to the squash commit that was synced from the origin (or upstream) repo, *not* my fork's pull request merge.

```
git reset --merge fb750f2
# (the hash fb750f2 is the hash of that squash commit, behind my undesired merge)
```

From what I know, `git reset HEAD^` would do the same here as using the `--merge` flag *if* your working directory was clean, which mine was. And `HEAD^` refers to the [first parent of the merge commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2222920/14390381).

2. **I made one new (simple) commit**, which was just fixing a little problem in one of the files. I intended to make this change anyway for my next PR contribution.

```bash
# ... changed file ...
git add .
git commit -m "...message here..."
```

Now, I had a *detached HEAD*.

3. **I fixed the detached HEAD** by performing the steps recommended in the SO answer linked above to rewrite `main` over to my new commit.

```bash
git branch -f main
# at this point, head is still detached and a regular push is rejected.
git checkout main
# now the history is changed! A force push is still required.
```

Locally, that undesired merge is finally off of `main`.

4. **I force pushed** these changes to my fork, rewriting the public `main` history:

```
git push --force
```

Finally, GitHub reports (as expected) my main branch is now 1 commit ahead of the origin, and that commit is my small new one I created which I welcome gladly.

**Regarding my initial utmost concerns:**
I believe this will cause no longer pose issues with future branches/PRs to the origin repo, because now the only diff between my fork's main versus the origin main is my one new commit (which fixes a little problem I intended to incorporate in a future PR anyway.)
As for the line connecting the branches `adding-pods` and `main` which I sought, I have decided to let go of that. It is not a necessity I see.